# Why flag retraction is necessary for marking a question unsalvageable?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, triage

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277397/eureka-netflix-learning) question. I flagged it **Off topic** since the user asked for recommendation of tutorial/documentation/book.
Stack Overflow asked me to retract my flag when I tried to mark it **Unsalvageable**. I want to ask: why is it necessary to retract my flag before marking a question unsalvageable? Why can't I flag and mark the question Unsalvageable at the same time?

I used the following workflow:

1. From the review queue, I opened the post in a new tab (Tab 2) to view it completely.
2. I flagged it Off Topic from Tab 2.
3. After some time, I returned to my review tab (Tab 1) and clicked on **Unsalvageable** button
4. Stack Overflow opened flag retraction window instead of skipping this question by detecting that it is already flagged by me.

Comment: You can. You have to click unsalvageable first, that brings up the flag menu and lets you flag it.  If you do it the other way around it doesn't know what to do since you can't flag something you already have a flag on.

Comment: @NathanOliver If that's the case, I'd argue that you shouldn't see a question in the review queue if you've already flagged it.

Comment: @Stijn It might.  I'm not sure how the OP is flagging them since that isn't an option.  If they are jumping to the post, flagging, and then trying to use unsalvageable then we can't stop that.  The workflow the OP used could use a little clarification.

Comment: @NathanOliver I have clarified the workflow I used.

Comment: @AbdulRaufMujahid Thanks.  You're going to want to get rid of step 2.

Comment: @NathanOliver Agreed. I should have directly flag it from review queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, the *Unsalvageable* review button just triggers the AJAX menu for flagging the post, basically as if you had clicked the *flag* link below the post outside the queue. You're getting the flag menu for if you already have a pending flag: it shows you what flag you raised and gives you a "retract" option. As pointed out in the comments, the solution is to flag it from review, without visiting the question itself.

I wouldn't worry about it too much. A queue like Triage will usually have enough review items to make up for this one item that you didn't get credit for, and getting the right moderation action in is more important than getting credit for it.

Comment: Oh dang, I didn't notice how old the question was.